# Why is browser tab history not maintained when redirects are fired by click()

Tags: javascript, click, browser-history

I'm finding that browser tab history is not maintained when redirects are fired by the click() method. This is an inconvenience to me and I'd very much like to get StackOverflow advice on the issue.

To elaborate, consider page1a.html coded thus:

```
<a href="page2.html">Redirect to Page 2</a>
```

When the user opens page1a in a new tab and clicks on the "Redirect to Page 2" link, this will display the content of page2.html - no surprises there. Moreover, as expected, the browser's back button will be enabled and will re-display page1 when clicked.

But a "dynamic" version, page1b.html of the above, behaves quite differently :

```
<a id="redirect" href="page2.html"></a>
<script>
document.onload = function () {
document.getElementById("redirect").click();
};
</script>
```

When page1b is run under the same conditions as above, page2 will certainly be displayed, as before, but the browser's back button will now **not** be enabled. There is no history. It is as if the fleeting existence of page1b in the tab had never occurred.

I can vaguely sense why this might be sensible behaviour on the part of the browser but it is causing me much grief as my application's version of page2 contains considerable dynamic interaction that may sometimes tempt a user to press the back button. I was relying on being able to "catch" the "back" intention in my application's version of page1 so that I can deal with this appropriately.

I can find no reference to any of this on web and was beginning to wonder if I'd hit a bug in Chrome, my browser of choice. Moreover, I could swear that things didn't **always** work like this. But a quick test in Opera seemed to show the same effect, so I seemed to have strayed somewhere down the line.

If the error is indeed mine, I'd be very grateful to anyone who can tell me where I'm going wrong. Alternatively, if it is confirmed that this is designed behaviour, can anyone suggest how it might be modified?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change

```
document.getElementById("redirect").click();
```

by

```
location.href = document.getElementById("redirect").href;
```

I hope this work.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't see that setting location.href is any help, but your comment alerted me to the eistence of window.location.assign(); as an alternative to click(). Unfortunately, this produces the same result - no history.

Comment: But the interesting thing about .assign is that while Mozilla's documentation for the function makes no reference to history, it points me to an alternative, namely location.replace. And this explicitly says that this version does not maintain tab history - implying that .assign does. The mystery deepens!

Comment: Add the end you may have to do it manually using `History` object [History.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Comment: replaced my .onload function with the following:

               const state = { 'page_id': 1, 'user_id': 5 };
               history.pushState(state, "test_page_1b", "test_page_1b.html");
               window.location.assign("test_page_2.html");

No difference!

Comment: I think it should be `history.pushState({}, "test page 2", "test_page_2.html")` then `window.location.assign("test_page_2.html")` pushState 3rd argument and assign argument should match.